# Which one do I need? EntityFramework.Core or EntityFramewor.MicrosoftSqlServer?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been trying to find out the differences between `EntityFramework.Core` and `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` to figure out which one of the packages I need. I did not notice until today that in my Visual Studio solution, which has both a WebUI project and DataAccess project, that the WebUI only includes `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` while the DataAccess project only includes `EntityFramework.Core`.

What is the real difference between the two and when should I include one vs. the other vs. both? I am using ASP.Net 5 Core for the entire solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` depends on `EntityFramework.Relational` which in turn depends on `EntityFramework.Core`. Restoring the project is about creating the dependency graph and installing all required packages (regardless of whether they were specified in your project.json or not) into the project. 
In your case you specified just EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer but during restore the other dependencies (including EntityFramework.Core) will be pulled so it is not necessary to specify EntityFramework.Core explicitly.

If you are on dnx you can see the dependency graph using `dnu list` (you can use the `--details` flag to see even more details) or, if you are brave, you can take a look at the project.lock.json file.

Comment: Is there any advantage to specifying only one versus both?

Comment: Advantage would be if you decided to move the `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` dependency to another project or if they decided to remove the `EntityFramework.Core` dependency from 'EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer' which they wont your code would still compile. Other than that there is no advantage

Comment: I wouldn't add implicit dependencies. It is more things to maintain and - as with betas - you may end up having some weird issues due to renames or version mismatches. Also, note that you already are not specifying all the implicit dependencies - you would have to add tens if not hundreds of package references to your project.json.

Comment: @Pawel So it would be fine and best if I just specify `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer`?

Answer (score 1):

Both are required but if you add `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` then `EntityFramework.Core` will be added for you as it is a required by `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer`.

`EntityFramework.Core` contains all of the core code of EntityFramework such as `DbContext`, `DbSet` and any `IQueryable extensions` aswell as alot of other internal code.

`EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` contains the database specific sql syntax and connection code for sql server. There are other database providers available.

Available database providers:

- `EntityFramework.InMemory` (this is good for writing tests that dont need a database)
- `EntityFramework.Sqlite`
- `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer`